# How to connect to a remote database with Windows authentication using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, sqlcmd, runas

I'm trying to use sqlcmd to execute querys on a remote database but I can´t login

When I connect using SSMS i have to use this runas command

```
runas /user:domain\username /netonly "Ssms.exe"
```

How can I log in like that using sqlcmd?

I´ve tried "-U domain\username -P password" and "-E" but none of those work.

I've also tried

```
runas /user:domain\username cmd.exe
```

to run cmd and then use sqlcmd from there but it says cmd.exe cannot be executed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can excute both `runas /user:domain\username cmd` and `runas /user:domain\username sqlcmd`. I couldn't try with another user however.

Comment: The `-U username` and `-P password` parameters are for SQL Login authentication and cannot be used with credentials for Windows authentication. The `-E` parameter is the correct one to use for Windows authentication, have you tried `runas ... sqlcmd ...` yet? The client computer (the one executing sqlcmd) needs to be in the same Active Directory/Kerberos domain as the SQL Server you're connecting to.

Comment: Getting command prompt, or powershell, to run under a different user I had no issues with, however, as soon as you try to use something like `sqlcmd` I got an error that the credentials were from an untrusted domain. Why do you need to run al your application specifically as a different user? Why not just actual log in as that user instead?